# Messaging latency in java (with zeromq)

Tags: java, zeromq

I just ran the zeroMQ hello world example and timed the request-response latency. It averaged about 0.1ms running using the IPC protocol. This sounds quite slow to me....Does this sound about right?

```
        long start=System.nanoTime();
        socket.send(request, 0);
        //  Get the reply.
        byte[] reply = socket.recv(0);
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime()-start)/1000000.0);
```

Comment: You realize your output is in tenths of milliseconds, yes?

Comment: You have over 30 questions without an accepted answer.  Perhaps you could review answers you have been given to see if they are acceptable.

Comment: Thx Brian....I've corrected my original post...its 0.1ms not 1 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your average had a sample of more than one? I would run the test for at least 2-10 seconds before taking an average. The average latency in the same process/thread may be misleading.

I would create a second process which echo everything it gets if you are not doing this already. (And divide the latency in two unless you want the RTT latency)

Plain Sockets can get a RTT latency of 20 micro-seconds on a typical multi-core box and I would expect IPC to be faster. On a fast PC you can get a typical RTT latency of 9 micro-second using sockets.

If you want latency much lower than this, I would consider doing everything in one process or one thread if you can, in which case the cost of a method call is around 10 ns (if its not inlined ;)

Comment: How much would this number change if I'm running on mac os x with lots of other threads running? Will the thread have to wait for its time slice before it runs?

Comment: The OS won't make much difference.  As long as you have a free core, the number of threads running doesn't matter so much.

Comment: I ran it for around 10 seconds and the lowest RTT was around 53 microseconds...I thought zeromq was supposed to be fast? Seems quite far off the 20 micro second mark you mentioned.

Comment: The hardware you use makes a big difference.  I have only tested on the latest processors.  Their benchmark is on older processors. The 9 us latency was on a 4.6 GHz i7. ;) Making sure you have a fast machine may be the simplest way to make your application go fast.